# Cannot run TopShelf install remotely using psexec

Tags: psexec, topshelf

I am trying to install a windows service on a remote machine.  The service is implemented using TopShelf.  I am running the following psexec command:

```
psexec \\remoteServerName "C:\PathToExe\TopShelfServiceName.exe" "install"
```

The error I am receiving is:
ERROR - The service terminated abnormally
Topshelf.HostConfigurationException: The service was not properly configured:
[Failure] Command Line An unknown command-line option was found: ARGUMENT: "install"

It appears that I am not running the TopShelf installer, rather executing my exe and passing "install" which is not a valid argument.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you need quotes around "install":

`psexec \\remoteServerName "C:\PathToExe\TopShelfServiceName.exe" install`